# Initialize a list from a function return in Scala

Tags: scala, list

How do you declare a list var that is initialized by the returning list of a funtion?

I want a `List[Any]`, let's call it `newList`, to be assigned to the values returned by some function, say `makeList()`, that returns a `List[Any]`.

like:

```
var newList = makeList(arg1, arg2)
```

Which gives an error: "Expression of type Any doesn't conform to expected type List[Any]"

I want to then index into the first element of newList like: `newList(0)`

I have tried `val newList : List[Any] = makeList(arg1, arg2)` 
but I still get that error message at `newList(0)`

I've confirmed that `makeList` returns a List[Any].

The last error is coming from having `newList(0)` as the last line in a function, so, the last question would be: what would the return type of a function need to be that returns an element of a List[Any], just Any?

Comment: Yes, that should work. What error are you getting? But note that both `var` (instead of `val`) and `List[Any]` (instead of something properly typed) are code smells.

Comment: Code smells? I"m getting an error message "Expression of type Any does not conform to expected type List[Any]"

Comment: `List[Any]` is a **bad** thing. It means the compiler has lost track of the type of the list's elements. It makes things much harder going forward.

Comment: If the list could have elements of mixed data types, or could be of a different depending on the parameters, is there another option for return datatype aside from List[Any]?

Comment: You still haven't provided enough detail for anyone to recreate the error you've described. Everything posted so far _should_ work. (It's bad practice but there's no reason for errors.)

Comment: You're right, that was working, I've updated with a follow up question @jwvh

Comment: Yes, every element of a `List[Any]` is type `Any`. At that point you've left the realm of Scala's strength and might consider switching to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are assigning is correct.

example,

```
scala> def makeList = List("scala", "clj", 1, 100.5)
makeList: List[Any]

scala> val newList = makeList
newList: List[Any] = List(scala, clj, 1, 100.5)

scala> newList = List("I want to change the reference of list")
<console>:12: error: reassignment to val
       newList = List("I want to change the reference of list")
               ^
```

in above example newList is `val` meaning you can't mutate it later.

using `var`, you can change the reference

```
scala> def makeList() : List[Any] = List("scala", "clj", 1, 100.5)
makeList: ()List[Any]

scala> var newList = makeList
newList: List[Any] = List(scala, clj, 1, 100.5)

scala> newList = List("I changed the reference of list")
newList: List[Any] = List(I changed the reference of list)
```

Comment: When I assign the var a value using a function that returns a list, I get an error saying "Expression of type Any does not conform to expected type List[Any]"

Comment: The signature is:  def scalarsToList(scalars: Map[String, JValue], definitions: List[(String, ScalarDefinition)]): List[Any] = {...}, so returning a List[Any]. This method works/was passing tests.

Comment: signature looks good to me. even `val newList : Any = makeList` should work, see the line number it failed

Comment: That removed the initial error, thank you. But now trying to access the first element in newList on the following line, like newList(0) gives an error: "Application does not take parameters"

Comment: Thats weird. wondering why `val newList  = scalarsToList(..)` does not work. you got second error because you assigned it to be `Any`, either cast it to `List[Any]` with `newList.asInstanceOf[List[Any]]` or use pattern match `newList match { case List[Any] => ...}`. But try to figure out why `val newList = scalarsToList ` is not working

Comment: Tried:  `val newList : List[Any] = makeList(arg1, arg2)
    newList(0)` but got the first error again "Expression of type Any does not conform to expected type List[Any]".

Comment: I doubt your method is returning `List[Any]`. Seems makeList is returning `Any`. Thats what the error is saying. Change the signature to `makeList: List[Any]` (see my second example)

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ, and checked by hovering over the return value in `makeList`, and it says it's a List[Any]

Comment: @user7804781, it might be helpful if you updated your original question with a complete not-working example, rather than going back and forth with individual lines spread in the comments